# How to extend HTML attributes in React with Typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, dom, attributes

When wrapping simple HTML elements, take for example this `MyLink` tag:

```
// MyLink.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Omit } from 'type-zoo';

interface MyLinkProps
  extends Omit<?, 'href'> {
  to: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const MyLinkProps: React.FC<MyLinkProps> = ({
  children,
  to,
  ...attributes
}) => (
  <a href={to} {...attributes}>
    {children}
  </a>
);

// Elsewhere
<MyLink to="https://example.com">Example</MyLink>
```

It seems I can swap out the `?` with any of the following:

- `React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>`
- `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>`
- `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>`

But what should one actually be using here? And if it varies, how does one choose?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would say `React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>` since this is the most descriptive type. For example if you wanted to provide a `ref` property to your anchor tag, you would need to use this type.

Comment: That seems sensible, and works for e.g. `<a>` tags.  What confused me was that it didn't work for `<svg>`. After some more fiddling, it seems the equivalent there must be `React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>`, but yeah. Do you know of any good React Typescript type overviews? Doesn't really seem mentioned at all in the documentation.

Comment: This is my goto resource for react typings: https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide

Comment: Thank you! Based on another SO post specifically about Divs, I had been using `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` which seems to accept all html attributes EXCEPT for href. All I can gather is that React.HTMLProps allows a super set of attributes.

Comment: when I provide a `ref` to my anchor tag and use `React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>` in my example, I get an error. Doesn't happen with `React.HTMLAttributes` or `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes`. I'm wrapping my element in styled component, though. But I always use `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` instead of what you suggest.

Answer (score 7):

I would choose `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` even if you are simply wrapping html elements because it is the interface that extends the most and can guard against typescript errors

In this example, I'm wrapping an html `<a>` element in styled component.

MyLink.tsx:

```
import { forwardRef, AnchorHTMLAttributes, HTMLAttributes, HTMLProps } from 'react'
import styled, { StyledComponent } from '@emotion/styled'
import { EmotionJSX } from '@emotion/react/types/jsx-namespace'

type AnchorProps = AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
// type AnchorProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
// type AnchorProps = HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement> // <~ THIS CAUSE ERROR

const StyledAnchor: StyledComponent<AnchorProps> = styled.a`
  color: red;
`

export default forwardRef<
  HTMLAnchorElement,
  AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
>((props: AnchorProps): EmotionJSX.Element => <StyledAnchor {...props} />)


// Elsewhere

const ref = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null)

<MyLink ref={ref} href="/">my link</MyLink>
```

if I choose `React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>`, then I will get typescript error:

```
Type 'StyledComponent<{ theme?: Theme | undefined; as?: ElementType<any> | undefined; }, DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>, {}>' is not assignable to type 'StyledComponent<AnchorProps, {}, {}>'.
  Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
    Type 'WeakValidationMap<{ theme?: Theme | undefined; as?: ElementType<any> | undefined; } & ClassAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<AnchorProps> | undefined'.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<{ theme?: Theme | undefined; as?: ElementType<any> | undefined; } & ClassAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<AnchorProps>'.
        Types of property 'as' are incompatible.
          Type 'Validator<ElementType<any> | null | undefined> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<string | null | undefined> | undefined'.
            Type 'Validator<ElementType<any> | null | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<string | null | undefined>'.
              Type 'ElementType<any> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | null | undefined'.
                Type 'ComponentClass<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

So I always use `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>`

Here are the react type interfaces:

- `interface HTMLProps<T> extends AllHTMLAttributes<T>, ClassAttributes<T>`
- `interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T>`
- `interface AnchorHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T>`